# Bootstrap dropdown and carousel not working suddenly, same code IS working on heroku

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I'm developing this basic website for a friend's personal sailing firm. Yesterday I've added a bit of language support and pushed to master, so he can look at my progress daily. The code works without a hitch on Heroku at: https://seastorm-sailing.herokuapp.com/sl

Locally however the dropdown and carousel is not working, in other words - Bootstrap JS is not working in my estimation. When I inspect network, everything is in place, tried opening it on my phone with ngrok, not working. I've deleted the repo locally and fresh pulled what I know works on Heroku from https://github.com/MerceneX/SeaStorm-Sailing and still no luck. I'm sorry if this is trivial, but I have tried everything that comes to my mind.

Website text is a bit lorem impsum and some parts are Slovene/English, depending on the language chosen.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I cloned your repo and ran it locally. Everything worked as expected. JS and CSS get loaded from local source not CDN, dropdown and carousel worked as well. tested it in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: I've done the same on a virtual machine without a hitch, yet on my laptop it will not work for the life of me... Might just have to develop in a VM :P
Do you have any idea as to what it could be? I'm ready to look into anything.